# Найти квадраты длины K на изображении

Tags: python, матрицы

Помогите найти количество квадратов длины `k`.
В моем случае их два, длиной стороны `k=2`.

[image]

Первое что пришло в голову пробежать - горизонтально, вертикально по двумерному списку и найти координаты потенциальных сторон квадрата
Сравнить их на наличие в двух словарях.

```
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)

width = len(img[0])
height = len(img)


def search_h(img, k):
    green_count = 0
    red_count = 0
    segment_count = 0
    square_side = 0
    coord_h = {}

    for h in range(height):
        for v in range(width):

            if img[h][v] == green:
                green_count += 1

            if img[h][v] == red:
                red_count += 1

            if img[h][v] == black:
                green_count = 0
                segment_count = 0
                red_count = 0

            if green_count == k and red_count > 1:
                segment_count += 1
                green_count = 1
                red_count = 0

            if segment_count == k:
                square_side += 1
                segment_count = 1
                coord_h[segment_count] = h, v

    return coord_h


coordinates_h = search_h(img, 2)


def search_v(img, k):
    green_count = 0
    red_count = 0
    segment_count = 0
    square_side = 0
    coord_v = {}

    for v in range(width):
        for h in range(height):
            if img[h][v] == green:
                green_count += 1

            if img[h][v] == red:
                red_count += 1

            if img[h][v] == black:
                green_count = 0
                segment_count = 0
                red_count = 0

            if green_count == k and red_count >= 1:
                segment_count += 1
                green_count = 1
                red_count = 0

            if segment_count == k:
                square_side += 1
                segment_count = 1
                coordV[segment_count] = v, h

    return coord_v


coordinates_v = search_v(img, k)

shared_items = {k: coordinates_v[k] for k in coordinates_h if k in coordinates_v and coordinates_v[k] == coordinates_v[k]}
num = len(shared_items)
return num
```

Comment: Давайте разделим задачу на части. Вы знаете шаг между рёбрами? Если да, то можно написать функцию, которая проверяет наличие горизонтального ребра по двум индексам (не координатам пикселей, а индексам). Например: есть ли горизонтальное ребро от третьего до четвертого столбца в пятом ряду сверху.

Такая же функция пишется для вертикальных рёбер.

Имея функции перебирайте столбцы и ряды и проверяйте наличие ребер для квадрата. Проверка одного квадрата - четыре теста по горизонтали и четыре теста по вертикали.

Answer (score 1):

Знаете, а мне понравилась задачка, что я её даже решил. :)

```
import cv2

# определение сетки точек
# возвращает координаты первой точки, последней точки, шаг, количество точек
# по-горизонтали и по-вертикали
def get_ranges(img):
    height, width, _ = img.shape
    for r in range(0, height, 8):
        for c in range(0, width, 8):
            if img[r,c][0] < 100 and img[r,c][1] > 100 and img[r,c][2] < 100:
                dots_c = []
                for ci in range(c, width, 8):
                    if img[r,ci][0] < 100 and img[r,ci][1] > 100 and img[r,ci][2] < 100:
                        dots_c.append(ci)
                dots_r = []
                for ri in range(r, height, 8):
                    if img[ri,c][0] < 100 and img[ri,c][1] > 100 and img[ri,c][2] < 100:
                        dots_r.append(ri)
                return {'C': (c, dots_c[-1], (dots_c[-1]-c)//(len(dots_c)-1), len(dots_c)), 
                        'R': (r, dots_r[-1], (dots_r[-1]-r)//(len(dots_r)-1), len(dots_r))}

# создаёт сетку граней на основе картинки и сетки точек
# грани определяются от каждой точки вниз и вправо
def get_edges(img, ranges):
    (cs, ce, ct, cn) = ranges['C']
    (rs, re, rt, rn) = ranges['R']
    edges_down = [[None]*cn for _ in range(rn-1)]
    for ri, r in enumerate(range(rs+rt//2, re-rt//2+1, rt)):
        for ci, c in enumerate(range(cs, ce+ct//2-1, ct)):
            edges_down[ri][ci] = img[r,c][0] > 100 or img[r,c][1] > 100 or img[r,c][2] > 100
    edges_right = [[None]*(cn-1) for _ in range(rn)]
    for ri, r in enumerate(range(rs, re+rt//2-1, rt)):
        for ci, c in enumerate(range(cs+ct//2, ce-ct//2+1, ct)):
            edges_right[ri][ci] = img[r,c][0] > 100 or img[r,c][1] > 100 or img[r,c][2] > 100
    return edges_down, edges_right

# поиск квадратов
# возвращает список координат левого верхнего угла найденных квадратов в сетке
def search(edges, k):
    edges_down, edges_right = edges
    found = []
    for r in range(len(edges_down)-k+1):
        for c in range(len(edges_right[0])-k+1):
            for ri in range(r, r+k):
                if not edges_down[ri][c] or not edges_down[ri][c+k]:
                    break
            else:
                for ci in range(c, c+k):
                    if not edges_right[r][ci] or not edges_right[r+k][ci]:
                        break
                else:
                    found.append((r, c))

    return found

# рисуем найденные квадраты поверх картинки и выводим на экран
def show_result(img, found, k, ranges):
    (cs, ce, ct, cn) = ranges['C']
    (rs, re, rt, rn) = ranges['R']
    img_out = img.copy()
    for r, c in found:
        cv2.rectangle(img_out, (c+cs+c*ct, r+rs+r*rt), (c+cs+(c+k)*ct, r+rs+(r+k)*rt), (255,255,255), 8)
    cv2.imshow(f"Found rectangles with k={k}", img_out)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#=============================================================
image = cv2.imread("edges.jpg")
ranges = get_ranges(image)
edges = get_edges(image, ranges)

K = 2
found = search(edges, K)
print("k =", K, found)
show_result(image, found, K, ranges)

K = 1
found = search(edges, K)
print("k =", K, found)
show_result(image, found, K, ranges)
```

```
k = 2 [(0, 3), (2, 4)]
k = 1 [(0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 3), (4, 3)]
```

[image: картинка]